# XML шаблон на сервере

Tags: xml, битрикс

Где лежит import.xml шаблон на сервере для выгрузки товаров из 1С?

```html
<КоммерческаяИнформация ВерсияСхемы="2.09" ДатаФормирования="2018-06-26T18:28:09">
    <Каталог СодержитТолькоИзменения="true">
        <Ид>12345678-ABCD-123A-4567-8910E1234DF5</Ид>
        <ИдКлассификатора>12345678-ABCD-123A-4567-8910E1234DF5</ИдКлассификатора>
        <Наименование>Каталог товаров</Наименование>
        <Товары>
            <Товар>
                <Ид>XML-ID - Товара A</Ид>
                <НомерВерсии>AAAAAQAAAHI=</НомерВерсии>
                <ПометкаУдаления>false</ПометкаУдаления>
                <Штрихкод/>
                <Артикул/>
                <Наименование>Название товара</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница>10</БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Группы>
                    <Ид>XML-ID - Категории товара</Ид>
                </Группы>
                <Описание/>
                <Страна/>
                <ЗначенияСвойств>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>XML-ID - Свойства A</Ид>
                        <Значение/>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>XML-ID - Свойства B</Ид>
                        <Значение/>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>XML-ID - Свойства C</Ид>
                        <Значение/>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                </ЗначенияСвойств>
                <СтавкиНалогов>
                    <СтавкаНалога>
                        <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
                        <Ставка>12</Ставка>
                    </СтавкаНалога>
                </СтавкиНалогов>
                <ЗначенияРеквизитов>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ВидНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Материал</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ТипНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                </ЗначенияРеквизитов>
                <Вес>0</Вес>
            </Товар>
         </Товары>
        <Описание>Описание каталога</Описание>
    </Каталог>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
```

Comment: Нет ниакого шаблона. Есть спецификация CommerceML или как там она называется, согласно которой и генерится файл.

Comment: Спасибо, буду туда копать